# Find sheet by name with tomorrow's date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a worksheet in Google Sheets with lots of Sheets, each representing a day - named in "dd/MM/yy ddd" format.

I need a function that will trigger daily at a certain time, looking for tomorrow's Sheet to copy data to another Sheet.

Comment: You can use the solution offered my Cooper below and put the last two lines in a function that will run on an installable time-driven trigger every day: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SheetName:

```
function getTomorrowsSheetName() {
  var today=new Date();
  //Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+1), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yy E"));
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+1), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yy E");
}
```

then use

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName(getTomorrowsSheetName());
```

[Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

[Javascript Date() Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

[Simple Date Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)